# SecondaryTile.DisplayName not getting updated

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I have the following code, which is supposed to update the text of a SecondaryTile.

```
async Task UpdateTile(SecondaryTile tile, string text)
{
    tile.DisplayName = text;
    await tile.UpdateAsync();
}
```

This code *does* work when I create the tile. But later when I try to update it after retrieving it with:

```
SecondaryTile tile = new SecondaryTile(id);
```

it doesn't work anymore, though a similar method that updates **the same tile**'s visuals *does* work. So I know I have the right tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it, the code works well. You could refer to the following code.

As follows:

```
// Initialize a secondary tile with the same tile ID you want to update
SecondaryTile tile = new SecondaryTile(tileId);
tile.DisplayName = "xxx";
// Show the display name on all sizes
tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = true;
tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnWide310x150Logo = true;
tile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare310x310Logo = true;
await tile.UpdateAsync();
```